# Facebook PHP SDK suddenly throwing Oauth error

Tags: php, facebook

Just recently i've started getting the following error when calling $facebook->api('/me');

03-03-2013 19:29:47: OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Currently i'm using the PHP SDK and up until a while go everything was fine, is this anything to do with any recent changes?

Before anyone asks yes my access token is valid, I log into my own app pretty much every day!

Thanks

Marc

Comment: what php sdk are you using?

Comment: We're on 3.1.1 at the moment.

Comment: you can try updating to 3.2.2 and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks travis i'm looking now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looka like a case of already existing bug.here is the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148). though it was expected to be fixed in php sdk v3.2.2 random occurance still exist.

hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh yeah, its when I make an ajax request this problem happens, basically my search system uses a lot of ajax to build up the search results..

Comment: lets hope for the fix soon.